# ruby multithreading - stop and resume specific thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I want to be able to stop and run specific thread in ruby in the following context:

```
thread_hash = Hash.new()
loop do
  Thread.start(call.function) do |execute|
    operation = execute.extract(some_value_from_incoming_message)
    if thread_hash.has_key? operation
      thread_hash[operation].run
    elsif !thread_hash.has_key?
      thread_hash[operation] = Thread.current
      do_something_else_1
      Thread.stop
      do_something_else_2
      Thread.stop
      do_something_else_3
      thread_hash.delete(operation)
    else
      exit
    end
  end
end
```

In human language script above acts as a server which receives a message, extracts some parameter from the incoming message. If that parameter is already in the thread_hash, suspended thread should be resumed.

If the parameter is not present in the thread_hash, parameter along with thread id is stored in the thread_hash, some function is executed and current thread is suspended until resumed in the new loop and again until do_something_else_3 function is executed and operation serviced in the current thread is removed from hash.

Can thread be resumed in Ruby based on thread id or should new thread be given name during start like

```
thr = Thread.start
```

and can be resumed only by this name like:

```
thr.run
```

Is the solution described above realistic? Could it cause some sort of leak/deadlock due to old thread resumption in the new thread or redundant threads are automatically taken care of by Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to do everything in every thread: read input, run existing threads, store new threads, delete old threads. Why not break up the problem?

```
hash = {}

loop do
  operation = get_value_from message

  if hash[operation] and hash[operation].alive?
    hash[operation].wakeup
  else
    hash[operation] = Thread.new do
      do_something1
      Thread.stop
      do_something2
      Thread.stop
      do_something3
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of wrapping the whole contents of the loop in a thread, only thread the message processing code. That lets it run in the background while the loop goes back to waiting for a message. This solves any sort of race/deadlock problem since all of the thread management occurs in the main thread.